# The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. - RESULT_INVALID_SIG

Tags: c#, api, desire2learn

Around 2 months ago, I applied for "App Developer Key" for D2L. My university will migrate to D2L soon, and they already set up it.

So, I applied for "domain limited" version. Now, when I check the system "Is Approved?" field is "True", which means, I think, I should be able to use it. I updated the Host, AppId, AppKey, UserId, UserKey fields in the sample "Getting Started" C# project of D2L (it is working with default values). But when I run it, I get an error:

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

When I checked the details the error is `RESULT_INVALID_SIG`. And, this type of error is returned "when the signature or id was invalid, typically this should trigger a reauthentication." So, what do you think? Is this because my role is student rather than admin? Or is this about AppId & AppKey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because you provided values for the `UserId` and `UserKey` fields for the sample, and those tokens were not appropriate for the host+AppID/Key pair that you have.

Try filling in the just the host field for your LMS, the App ID and Key fields with the App credentials you have, and then see if you can get the sample going that way:

- You should be able to make a "Get Versions" call with no user credentials at all (because you can make that call anonymously.
- To retrieve user credentials that match your app + AppID/Key pair, provide just the host, and app credentials, and then 'Authenticate' -- the authentication process should generate a UserID/Key pair and populate those fields -- you can then cache all those credential values and use them with the same app/LMS combination going forward (as long as your user tokens don't expire).

Comment: I did not provide values for UserId and UserKey fields for "Get Version" method, but it is not working.

Then, I thought this could be related to wrong port#. I set it 443, but do not know what it is exactly. I set the port# wrong for D2L test-server in the working project file, and I got a different error: "Unable to connect to the remote server". So, I do not think it is about port#.
My guess is that this is about api-related permission issue in the server.The administrator need to change the settings in the server accordingly, so that access through API could be possible. What do you think?

Comment: No, the "invalid signature" response you're getting is strictly because you're passing in a signature token, either app signature or user signature that the LMS cannot verify: it doesn't have anything to do with permissions. The API call hasn't gotten to the point where user role permissions would come into play at all.